# How to re-render child component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Load (child) will send a value to Parent component then it will be set in state and passed down to Backbutton (child).

Backbutton (child) will return the props back to the parent when clicked. Parent will set state based on the return value and pass it down back to Load (child) component.

**Problem:**  For couple of clicks it works fine, but then it stops re-rendering Load (child) component. Parent logs shows that it is receiving data from Backbutton (child) but somehow it does not show logs in Load.

Parent:

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      loadDirs: '',
      backDirs: ''
    }
  }  

getLoad = (info) => {
    this.setState({ loadDirs: info });
  }

  goBack = (instruct) => {
    this.setState({ backDirs: instruct },
      () => { console.log(this.state.backDirs) });
  }

render() {

   return (
          <div> 
             <Backbutton dirs={this.state.loadDirs} backbutton={this.goBack} />
              <Load backload={this.state.backDirs} load={this.getLoad} />  
           </div>
       );
     }
}
```

Backbutton (Child):

```
class Backbutton extends Component {
    constructor({props, dirs}) {
        super(props, dirs);
    }

    prevLink(info) {
        let backlink = info.toString().substr(0, info.toString().lastIndexOf('/') + 0);
        console.log(backlink);
        this.props.backbutton(backlink);
    }


    render() {

        return (
            <button key={this.props.dirs} 
            onClick={() => { this.prevLink(this.props.dirs) }}>
            Back</button>

        )
    }
}


export default Backbutton;
```

Load (Child):

```
....
  componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
  if (this.props.backload !== prevProps.backload) {
    console.log(this.props.backload)
    this.allFetch(this.props.backload);
  }
}
....
```

**Edited:**
I have couple of questions now:

1) I am now calling child method from parent using Refs (reference) and my app is working as expected. But I read it in the react docs that refs should be avoided. Should I really not use refs?

2) Since componentDidUpdate didn't work for me. Can anybody guide me with any better alternative or why is it not working?

I don't know why after couple of clicks Parent suddenly stops re-rendering child component when using componentDidUpdate so I ended up using refs because I wanted to trigger fetch API method every time data changes by clicking button.

Comment: does this.allFetch(this.props.backload) setState?

Comment: @JunBin it fetches API from backend

Comment: You need to set this.props.backload as a state in Load so you do, if(this.state.backload !== nextProps.backload)

Comment: @JunBin its not showing logs in Load after couple of clicks. So it will stop setState as well.

Comment: console.log(nextProps.backload) gets anything?

Comment: @JunBin Please provide an example rather than speculating untested suggestions.

Comment: is your Load PureComponent?

Comment: @eramit2010 No, it is not.

Comment: did you verify that is `this.props.backload === nextProps.backload`? in your componentdidupdate

Comment: @AseemUpadhyay yes. If I do `this.props.backload === nextProps.backload` then my app crashes.

Comment: i wasn't mentioning you to change the condition, i am asking that can you check that your previous backload is equal to nextprops backload? maybe that is why your component isn't working after few clicks, maybe the data you are checking hasnt changed after a few clicks.

Comment: @AseemUpadhyay on my first click I get response from this.props.backload and on second click I get from nextProps.backload 
`componentDidUpdate(nextProps) {
  if (this.props.backload.length > 0 && this.props.backload !== nextProps.backload) {
    console.log(this.props.backload)
  } else if (this.props.backload.length > 0 && nextProps.backload) {
    console.log(nextProps.backload)
  }
}`